# Load select function on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have select list like this:

```
function chargeC() {
  apiService.get("../../api/Catalogos/", null,
    function (res) {
      $scope.Catalogos = res.data;
      $scope.selected = $scope.Catalogos[0];
    }, errorCatalogo);
}
```

As you can see my default value is `$scope.Catalogos[0]`

When I select one value of select list it load new function:

```
$scope.filtro = function (selected) {
apiService.get("../../api/Catalogo/GetCatalogoRegistro/" + selected.ID);
```

I want to load this second function when page load with my default value `$scope.Catalogos[0]`, how can I achieve it?

I try with

```
select.firstElementChild.click();
```

or

```
$(chargeC).trigger($scope.filtro);
```

But don´t work

Comment: trigger the change event?

Comment: I try  `$(chargeC).trigger($scope.filtro);` but I get Cannot convert undefined or null to object @mplungjan

Comment: Add `$scope.filtro($scope.selected);` next to `$scope.selected = $scope.Catalogos[0];`

Comment: ALL I NEEDED! THANKS! @gilango